# Block access to safe mode windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, safe-mode

How do I block access to safe mode from the shift+restart method and startup?
Tried renaming registry folders but it wont let me.
Tried this command bcdedit /set {bootmgr} displaybootmenu no, Doesn't work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you disable safe mode? If your computer gets a startup problem, and safe-mode would be unavailable, then you would have pretty much nothing to fix your computer.

Comment: @Jim I like to live life on the edge

Answer (score 1):

Shamelessly copied from this [link](https://thetechnologygeek.org/disable-windows-safe-mode/) for quick reference

> To Disable Safe mode first
>
> Go to Start> Run
>
> Type regedit and click OK
>
> Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESystemCurrentControlSetControlSafeBoot
>
> Expand SafeBoot by clicking the + sign and you should see 2 keys with
>   the name Minimal and Network.
>
> Before you can rename the keys you must give yourself permissions to
>   the keys.  Remove inherited right and apply rights to child objects.
>   You many also want to take ownership of the key.
>
> Rename both of the keys to something else, example, Minimal to
>   MinimalX and Network to NetworkX.?

Or

Try this software : https://www.raymond.cc/blog/disable-f8-key-to-block-access-to-safe-mode-during-windows-startup/

If methods don't work then use the following this [reference](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/disable-f8-key-to-block-access-to-safe-mode-during-windows-startup/) from Windows XP